# Table formulas return "Subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to enter formulas into tables.

Sometimes I get "Subscript out of range". It doesn't matter how I write the formula, it never works consistently.

You'll see a different formula commented out which doesn't work either.

```vb
Sub UpdateAccountTable()
    'PURPOSE: Update table data with current data from CW Data Table
    'Erik 2022
    '
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tName As String
    Dim warnCol As Long
    Dim limitCol As Long

    Range("L4").Select
    tName = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name   'gets table name
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tName)
    warnCol = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Find("Current Warn").Column    
    limitCol = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells.Find("Current Limit").Column
    ' warn and limitcol gets column number because the columns are not always in the same place
        
    StopExcelActions  'function to stop calculate, screen updating ect
    
    With tbl
        .ListColumns("warnCol").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=INDEX(CWdata[Warn Value],MATCH([@Helper],CWdata[Helper],0))"
    '    "=SUMIFS(CWdata[Warn Value], CWdata[Policy Name],[@[Policy Name]],CWdata[Rule Name],[@[Evaluator Description]])"
        .ListColumns("limitCol").DataBodyRange.Formula = "=INDEX(CWdata[limit Value],MATCH([@Helper],CWdata[Helper],0))"
    '   "=SUMIFS(CWdata[Limit Value], CWdata[Policy Name],[@[Policy Name]],CWdata[Rule Name],[@[Evaluator Description]])"
    End With
    
    'Range("M4:N4").Select
    With tbl.ListColumns("warnCol")
        .EntireColumn.Copy
        .EntireColumn.xlpastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
    With tbl.ListColumns("limitCol")
        .EntireColumn.Copy
        .EntireColumn.xlpastespecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
     
    StartExcelActions
    Set tbl = Nothing
    FormatData
End Sub
```

The error:
[image]

Comment: warnCol is a long and you use it as column index. Therefore you have to write `.ListColumns(warnCol).` Alternatively you could write `.ListColumns("Current Warn")` instead - by that you wouldn't need to search for the header

Comment: Three thoughts:  1) remember to look at and correct other lines in your code where you use .ListColumns  2)  May be useful to look at how the ListColumns "Item" property works (or any Item property)  Note that:  ListColumns.Item(variant) where variant is either the stringName or the indexNumber of the column.   and then 3) May therefore be useful to see how/why the usage ListColumns(stringName) or ListColumns(indexNumber) returns the .ltem Property.

Comment: Thank you Ike!  I had it that way originally, it worked for a while then broke, I saw in another code to add the Quotes around it.  then that worked for a while.  It's baffling! but working again.  

Thank you also John, I'll play around with your suggestion too.  I feel like I should just learn how to use collections and do it that way, but so far that's beyond my VBA skills.

Comment: So, here we are.  Ran fine for 5 worksheets then I get application defined or object defined error.  Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how your use of `tbl.ListColumns(....) is one of those times where VBA is defaulting to the "Item Property" of the ListColumns object.

So:

`ListColumns(StringName)` or `listColumns(IndexNumber)`
are coding variations that point to the "Item" property: `ListColumns.Item(variant)`

Then notice how you must use the stringName for the column you have, not the String which is the name of the variable you used to store the string.   Similarly, if you're using the "indexNumber" version of the object property, you use the value stored in the variable, not the string name of your indexNumber variable.

I give myself a heads up, as I code, and explicitly name all string variables as str_someName, and all indexes as j_someIndexName -- therefore:

```
Dim str_someName as string  
Dim j_someIndexingName as Long 
    ' you might have written Dim jLong_warnCol as Long
```

If I wrote `ListColumns("str_someName")` I would see right off that I'm using the *string of my variable name*, and not the *value* stored within the string variable.  Similarly, if you wrote `ListColumns("j_someIndexName")`, you might notice that was weird.

Using the naming convention for Long or Integers becomes useful in Loops, so your variables have some expected range of values:  `Dim long_someName as Long` or `Dim j_someName' as Integer`.   You could extend this habit by using "t_..." for table variables, "obj_..." for objects, and on and on.   Forced name conventions also helped me learn to avoid coding problems when crafting SQL statements, themselves stored into a str_sql string variable.

The use of OPTION EXPLICIT is an additional check.